# How to prove that $f(t)\to 0$ as $t\to+\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If $f(t)$ is smooth enough and if $f(t)\in L^1(0,+\infty)\cap L^\infty(0,+\infty)$ and $\frac{d}{dt}f(t)\in L^2(0,+\infty)$, how to prove that $f(t)\to 0$ as $t\to+\infty$.

I know if $f(t)\not\to 0$ as $t\to+\infty$, then there are $t_n$ s.t. $f(t_n)=c_n\geq c_0>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: Note that $ff' \in L^{1}$by Holder's inequality. [$f^{2}$ is integrable: $\int f^{2}\leq \|f\|_{\infty} \int |f|$].

[ I write $f'(x)$ for $\frac {df(x)} {dx}$].

Hence, $[f(s)]^{2}-[f(t)]^{2}=2\int_t^{s} f(x)f'(x)dx \to 0$ as $s >t \to \infty$. Use completeness of $\mathbb R$ to show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} [f(x)]^{2}$ exists. This limit must be $0$ because $f^{2}$ is integrable.